# Unable to fix Readiness Probe for redis-replica pod

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I have a K8s Redis pod with 1 master and 1 replcia config. Replica POD is getting Readiness probe failed after restoring the data , restarting it from stateful set and also after deleting the POD. However the master single alone is working fine without replica.

Below is the helm chart for that.
readinessProbe:
enabled: true
failureThreshold: 5
initialDelaySeconds: 100
periodSeconds: 5
successThreshold: 1
timeoutSeconds: 3